# Can multiple callers subscribe to the same async function, using the Babel await keyword?

Tags: javascript, async-await, babeljs, es6-promise

Multiple callers can subscribe to a function in progress if it returns a CommonJS promise:

```
let curWaitTask;
let lastWaitTime = new Date(1970, 0, 1);
let func1 = function() {
  if(curWaitTask) {
    return curWaitTask;
  }
  if((new Date() - lastWaitTime) > TWENTY_MINUTES) {
    lastWaitTime = new Date();
    curWaitTask = func2().then(func3).then(func4);
    return curWaitTask;
  }
}
```

Above is an expiring cache approach. The first call to `func1` that happens after the twenty minute cache expires will cause the service to perform another async operation to update the cache. In the meantime, other calls to `func1` may occur, which will await the same cache update operation instead of it happening again and again until the cache gets set (multiple times in a row, due to the all the calls).

Is there some way to get this behavior while using the clarity offered by the Babel `await` keyword, instead of a string of unwieldy `.then()`'s? In practice, it is getting ugly.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  Can't you just write `result = await operation()`?

Comment: @Casey: Say ```operation()``` takes a long time, like 1 minute. If the ```await operation()``` line is called 10 times in a 5 second period, it will execute the whole 1 minute call 10 times. But in the ```func1``` example I gave, the long ```func2.then(func3).then(func4)``` chain only happens the first time, and the following 9 calls to ```func1()``` will wait for the result of the first promise. See the difference?

Comment: I see.  But can't you just issue `curwaittask = await func1()` and then loop?

Comment: Is `lastWaitTime` ever updated? And what should a call to `func1` do when there is neither a cached value nor timeout expired?

Comment: Surely you meant `func2()` not `func2`?

Comment: @Bergi: Thx, good catch on ```func2()```. The set of ```lastWaitTime``` was assumed to happen within ```func4``` but I set it above for clarity.

Comment: @BrandonArnold Thanks, I updated my answer. Setting `lastWaitTime` in `func4` vs before the `then` chain makes some timing difference but doesn't change the answer. Regardless, you still didn't answer the question what should happen when there is no `curWaitTask` but the `lastWaitTime` has not yet expired?

Comment: @BrandonArnold Also, is `curWaitTask` ever unset or does the value stay there forever?

Comment: @Bergi: Thanks, I think I like your answer below, reviewing it now. It is assumed the condition never occurs that ```curWaitTask``` is null except on the first iteration. Conceivably the ```.then``` chain may throw or return null but I don't think it makes the problem any clearer to account for those errors. Just illustrating the method.

Comment: I do see the point of your question now. I'm typing on my phone, will have to review the code segment I copied this from to see what I got out of order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just wrap the "unwieldy `then` chain" in an `async function` and use `await` in there:

```
let curWaitTask;
let lastWaitTime = new Date(1970, 0, 1);
function func1() {
  if (!curWaitTask && (new Date() - lastWaitTime) > TWENTY_MINUTES) {
    lastWaitTime = new Date();
    curWaitTask = doTask();
  }
  return curWaitTask;
}
async function doTask() {
  return func4(await func3(await func2()));
}
```

It is (fortunately?) not possible inside an `async function` to refer to the new promise that is created from the current invocation, so using `async function func1` is not really sensible here.

Answer (score 2):

You asked if multiple callers could subscribe to the same *async* function, so let's see if we can solve this within `func1` and keep it async (with help from Bergi!):

```
let curTask;
let lastTime = new Date(1970, 0, 1);

async function func1() {
  if (curTask && (new Date() - lastTime) < 10000) {
    return await curTask;
  }
  return await (curTask = (async () => {
    lastTime = new Date();
    return await func4(await func3(await func2()));
  })());
}
```

We can await promises, not just async functions.

We put the meat of the work in a second async function that we don't immediately await, thereby getting its promise instead, which we initialize `curTask` with synchronously.

Comment: That usage of `new Promise` and `resolve`/`reject` is quite questionable and highly error-prone. I'd rather recommend to use an `async` immediately-invoked function expression if you really needed something like this.

Comment: @Bergi Questionable no doubt, but error-prone? It pretty much mimics a promise constructor pattern inside an async function, except I'm not passing an actual async function to a promise constructor... Maybe I should try that...

Comment: Error-prone for three reasons: you might forget the `try`/`catch` (especially [inside `new Promise`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572)) and not `reject` when appropriate, you might forget to `resolve` the promise (but try to `return` instead), or you might accidentally try to `await curTask` before calling `resolve`. Therefore, a rule of thumb: don't use `async function`s inside the promise constructor. Just do `curTask = (async () => { …; return …; }())`.

Comment: @Bergi You're right that does basically accomplish the same thing, and simpler. Sweet, thanks!